# How can i skip few columns using column header from below code

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple columns with different headers, I would like to skip a few columns using column header, not sure about their placement, they will be in column B or C in code below
Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

below code works fine to fill the blanks with an above value such as filldown
Please help

```
 Sub FillRows()
     Const SheetName As String = "Close Price"

Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long, y
Dim arColumns
arColumns = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

With Worksheets(SheetName)
    lastRow = .Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 3 To lastRow
        For y = 0 To UBound(arColumns)
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(x, arColumns(y)).Value) Then .Cells(x, arColumns(y)).Value = .Cells(x - 1, arColumns(y)).Value

        Next
    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe what you want is instead using column names, find random strings on the headers? If so you `arColumns`should hold these strings and then use a variable holding `Col = .Cells.Find(arColumns(y)).Column`

Comment: Almost similar situation, but instead of searching I just want to use code as it is arColumns = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), and skip the column B which as column header "XYZ", i don't want to run my code on column header "XYZ"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, There is no data example, so I made up my own one. I did just a range of data starting in `A1` and 5 columns. Header in column B is `XYZ`

[image]

Red cells are the blank ones. We want to do something will all blank cells in range, excluding those in column where header is equal to `XYZ`.

So my code, first, gets the last row of the range, then it selects at once all blank cells, and then, 1 by 1, it checks if the header is `XYZ` or not. IF not, then it does something (in my code, just print adress of those blank cells).

```
Dim sCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Dim arColumns As Variant
arColumns = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

'we need to get the real last row of complete range
'so we need to check all columns because it could be
'that last cell of a column is a blank


For i = 0 To UBound(arColumns) Step 1
    If Range(arColumns(i) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > LastRow Then
        LastRow = Range(arColumns(i) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
Next i

Range("A1:E" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select 'we select all blank cells only

For Each sCell In Selection
    If Cells(1, sCell.Column).Value <> "XYZ" Then
        'If first cell in this same column IS NOT = XYZ then do something
        'You can add to skip extra columns adding OR conditions to IF
        Debug.Print sCell.Address(False, False)
    End If
Next sCell
```

Executing this code gets an output of only blank cells addresses but none of them are on column B, because header in column B is `XYZ`.

```
C2
D2
A3
E3
A5
C8
E9
E10
D11
A13
C15
C17
E17
A19
D19
A23
E23
```

The good thing is that you can add extra checks in the IF part with OR/AND conditions if you need them. Something like `If Cells(1, sCell.Column).Value <> "XYZ" Or Cells(1, sCell.Column).Value="ABC" Then` would skip the blank cell if header is `XYZ` or `ABC`

Hope you can adap this to your needs.